# php preg_replace for property inside html tags

Tags: php, regex, tags, html-parsing

My problem is how to replace the `src` value of a `<script>` tag inside a string like in this example (well, I need this in a more general scenario of properties inside tags):

```
$data = <<<EOD
<script language="javascript" src= "../tests/ajax-navigation.js"></script>
...
<img src="../404.jpg" alt="404">
...
EOD;
```

I used this function in php:

```
class Search{
 public static function replaceProperty($data, $start, $end, $property, $alias, $limit = -1){
   //get blocks formed as: $start $property = "..." $end or $start $property = '...' $end
   $pattern = "!(".$start."){1}(.*?)".$property."\s*=\s*[\"\'](.*?)[\"\'](.*?)(".$end."){1}!s";
   $data = \preg_replace($pattern, "{$start}\${2}{$property}=\"{$alias}\"\${4}{$end}", $data, $limit);
   return $data;
 }
}
```

which I called like this:

```
 $data = Search::replaceProperty($data, "<script", ">", "src", $alias);
```

What is really strange is that both tags `<script>` and `<img>` get changed!
Of course I can call it like

```
 $data = Search::replaceProperty($data, "<script", "</script>", "src", $alias);
```

but this doesn't answer the general case!

**Just to clarify some points with regex:**

i. the actual string to search for is:

```
$data = <<<EOD
<script language="javascript" src= "../tests/ajax-navigation.js"></script>
...
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
...
<img src="../404.jpg" alt="404">
...
EOD;
```

ii. the regex `$pattern = "!(".$start."){1}(.*?)".$property."\s*=\s*[\"\'](.*?)[\"\'](.*?)(".$end."){1}!s";` or in the simplest form `$pattern = "%".$start."(.*?)".$property."\s*=\s*[\"\'](.*?)[\"\'](.*?)".$end."%s";` (just 3 subpatterns) identifies the first `<script>` as expected but...it takes the second `<script>` and terminates at the `>` of the first `<img>` changing whatever `src` property it finds in between!

iii. by deleting the `s` metacharacter at the end of the pattern resulting in `$pattern = "%".$start."(.*?)".$property."\s*=\s*[\"\'](.*?)[\"\'](.*?)".$end."%";` behaves as expected but fails when the tags are broken with enters:

```
<script language="javascript" src= "../tests/ajax-navigation.js"
></script>
```

iv. and, of course my intention is to replace and not to delete the value at `src` property.

Hope these clarify my question.

Comment: I decided to use DOMDocument and post a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031974/replace-property-of-an-html-tag-with-phps-domdocument

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
 public static function replaceProperty($data, $start, $end, $property, $alias, $limit = -1){
```

To this:

```
 public static function replaceProperty($data, $start, $end, $property, $alias='', $limit = -1){
```

Adding a default value of '' to the $alias parameter.

Also not sure what the backslash in front of the preg_replace is doing there.  I had to remove that too.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it seems I didn't explain well my $alias variable: should get any value like $alias = "some value here". My purpose is to replace not to delete the src property! (my backslash denotes php's namespace as all my code is under a different namespace)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I used to find all of a certain element with preg_match_all, I've found that preg_match_all is better for doing this than preg_match.

```
$arr = array();
preg_match_all("%[<]script.*?[>](.*?)[<][\/]script[>]%",$f, $arr, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
var_dump($arr);
```

Or with preg_replace:

```
$a = preg_replace("%[<]H3.*?[>].*?[<][\/]H3[>]%", "", $a);
```

Try preg_match all while following the syntax I used putting `<` and `>` like [<]$start instead of passing the `<` to the function. Also make sure it isn't case sensitive by using the respective preg_match options after % or convert all data using strtolower before.  I'm sure if this works you can figure the rest out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As I said I'll use `DOMDocument()` but here is an answer with regex:

```
class Search{

public function __construct(){}

public static function replaceProperty($data, $tag, $property, $alias, $limit = -1){
   //get blocks formed as: <$tag...$property=["|']...["|']...[/>|>]
   $pattern = '%<\s*'.$tag.'(\s+(\w+)(\s*\=\s*(\'|"|)(.*?)\\4\s*)?)*\s*(\/>|>)%s';
   $result = \preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
   if(!empty($result)){
      $search = array();
      $replace = array();
      //found them at index = 0!
      foreach($matches[0] as $i=>$found){
         if(($limit >= 0) && ($i >= $limit))
            break;
         if(isset($matches[2]) && isset($matches[5]) && $matches[2][$i] == $property){
            $search[] = $found;
            $replace[] = \str_replace($matches[5][$i], $alias, $found);
         }
      }
      $data = \str_replace($search, $replace, $data);
   }
   return $data;
}
}
```

and called like this:

```
$data = Search::replaceProperty($data, "script", "src", $alias);
```

I used Emanuele Del Grande's answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1) post which might is a reproduction of posts like [this](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/match-innermost-html-element)!
Thanks.