# Replace property of an html tag with php's DOMDocument

Tags: php, replace, tags, domdocument

My problem is how to replace the `src` value of a `<script>` tag inside a string like in this example (well, I need this in a more general scenario of properties inside tags):

```
$data = <<<EOD
<script language="javascript" src= "../tests/ajax-navigation.js"></script>
...
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
...
<img src="../404.jpg" alt="404">
...
EOD;
```

I posted another question with `preg_replace()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004904/php-preg-replace-for-property-inside-html-tags) but as there is a great debate about this I decided to use `DOMDocument` with this function in php:

```
public static function replacePropertyDOM($html, $tag, $property, $alias){
   $dom = new \DOMDocument();
   @$dom->loadHTML($html);
   $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
   $els = $dom->getElementsByTagName($tag);
   foreach($els as $el){
      if($el->hasAttribute($property)){
         $el->removeAttribute($property);
         $el->setAttribute($property, $alias);
      }
   }
   return $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

which I called like this:

```
 $data = Search::replacePropertyDOM($data, "script", "src", $alias);
```

I have some questions though:

- it seems that `DOMDocument` doesn't preserve all my newlines in code
- if I use `$dom->loadHTML($html);` without `@` I catch warnings with code number 2 like these:

  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : link in Entity, line: 9

for a link in `<head>` like this one

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../tests/ajax-navigation.css"></link>
```

or even worse

```
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : b in Entity, line: 33
```

for a js comand

```
mydebug.innerHTML = '<p><b>Test $$.ccl.ajax.getInstance()</b></p>';
```

- and a last one: wouldn't be better to find these tags and proceed to a string-replace inside my data so no more formating errors when returning the html string?

**Ok I'll stick with my solution with a minor change**

```
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$dom->formatOutput = true;
```

thus, `DOMDocument` takes the decision on how to nicely format the output and being more reflexive of what we should expect!

Comment: It looks like you're needlessly complicating your life. Why can't you just put there the correct `src` instead of laboriously replacing it?

Comment: See [`libxml_use_internal_errors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php)

Comment: @MightyPork: it's part of a more complicating system envolving use of php as a proxy and so on...